# Como reaproveitar um componente React exibindo-o de maneira diferente?

Tags: react

Tenho um componente chamado `Header` e desejo reaproveitá-lo em mais algumas páginas. Quando faço o `import Header from './Header'` e chamo ele na página desejada, está tudo certo.

O que eu desejo é trazer o componente sem o `Button` para a nova página. Como posso fazer isso?

Componente pai:

```js
const PageDefault = () => {
  return <Header />;
};
    
export default PageDefault;
```

Componente `Header`:

```js
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="Header">
      <Link to="/">
        <img className="Sena" src={Sena} alt="sena imagem" />
      </Link>

      <Button as={Link} className="Button" to="/sena/bel">
        Registrar
      </Button>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se faz sentido esse botão fazer parte do `Header` e aparecer em apenas algumas ocasiões, você pode fazer:

```js
const Header = ({ withButton }) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Link />

      {withButton && <Button />}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

E quando quiser que ele tenha o botão, usar:

```js
return <Header withButton={true} />; // Ou <Header withButton />
```

---

Caso esse botão seja um conteúdo extra de uma tela específica, você pode receber um componente como prop:

```js
const Header = ({ extraContent }) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Link />

      {extraContent}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

E chamar o componente desse modo:

```js
const button = <Button />;

return <Header extraContent={button} />
```

Comment: Opa!!! Muito obrigado!! Era isso mesmo que estava precisando! Conseguir solucionar aqui. Grato!!!